# Get rid of single quotes from the substituted string within sed command in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, bash, sed

I have a text file `1.txt` which has following content:

```
module abc
```

I am trying to generate multi-line string that I need to add before `module abc` line in `1.txt`. I am using `sed` to do this.

```
>>> match = ['a_defs', 'b_defs', 'c_defs']
>>> inc_str = ("\n").join(['`include "%s.vh"' % str for str in match])
>>> print("include string: ", inc_str)
include string:  `include "a_defs.vh"
`include "b_defs.vh"
`include "c_defs.vh"
```

This is the `sed` command I am forming and printing before executing it:

```
>>> print("sed -i '/module abc/i %s' 1.txt" % inc_str)
sed -i '/module abc/i '`include "a_defs.vh"\n`include "b_defs.vh"\n`include "c_defs.vh"'' 1.txt
```

When I execute the above `sed` command, I get error:

```
> sed -i '/module abc/i '`include "a_defs.vh"\n`include "b_defs.vh"\n`include "c_defs.vh"'' 1.txt
Unmatched `.
```

There shouldn't be `'` before and after the string that gets substituted in the `sed` command, but not sure how to get rid of them.
This behavior is with `Python3.10`.

This works fine:

> sed -i '/module abc/i `include "a_defs.vh"\n`include "b_defs.vh"\n`include "c_defs.vh"' 1.txt

This is the behavior in `Python2.7`:

```
> python2
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> match = ['a_defs', 'b_defs', 'c_defs']
>>> inc_str = ("\n").join(['`include "%s.vh"' % str for str in match])
>>> print("sed -i '/module abc/i %s' 1.txt" % inc_str)
sed -i '/module abc/i `include "a_defs.vh"
`include "b_defs.vh"
`include "c_defs.vh"' 1.txt
```

I tried `repr`, `strip`, but didn't help. Can someone please help me resolving this?

Comment: Why are there backticks in front of your include keywords?

Comment: That is the syntax.

Comment: But they are outside of the single quoted string, so shell tries to execute the command inside of pair of backticks. There are three of them, so shell complains about missing backtick. I really don't know how you got such result, I tried your commands both with python2 and python3 and got the same result as in your 'this works fine' example.

Comment: When I execute this - `print("sed -i '/module abc/i %s' 1.txt" % inc_str)`, inc_str is substituted with `'<value of inc_str>'` and those single quotes are creating problem. You do not see this behavior?

Comment: No: My output is: `>>> print("sed -i '/module abc/i %s' 1.txt" % inc_str)[here is the line break]
sed -i '/module abc/i \`include "a_defs.vh"
\`include "b_defs.vh"
\`include "c_defs.vh"' 1.txt`

Comment: I am not sure how this behavior can be different. I am on Python 3.10.1

Comment: My `python3 --version` returns `Python 3.6.9`. You can try to concatenate the strings, e.g. `"sed -i '/module abc/i " + inc_str + "' 1.txt"`

Comment: Even with your suggestion, the result is same as what I updated for Python2.7, and same result with Python3.10 also - `>>> print("sed -i '/module abc/i " + inc_str + "' 1.txt")`
`

Comment: What's wrong with the python 2.7 version? You don't want newlines? Then try `print("sed -i '/module abc/i %s' 1.txt" % inc_str.replace('\n', ' '))`

Comment: You last comment did the trick! sed command doesn't like newlines. If you can post your last comment as an answer, I can accept it as an answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: But now I see all the include lines in one line :(, that is not what I wanted. In file, all include lines should have been written on new lines. sed command doesn't like \n but in file, all include lines should be on new lines.

Comment: Change ' ' to '\\n' and you are good ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert newlines to \n characters (which means 'newline' to sed) just substitute them using following statement:

```
>>> print("sed -i '/module abc/i %s' 1.txt" % inc_str.replace('\n', '\\n'))
sed -i '/module abc/i `include "a_defs.vh"\n`include "b_defs.vh"\n`include "c_defs.vh"' 1.txt
```